# How to draw a circle with a transparent middle

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a white circle with the following code:

```
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mPaint);
```

But it is being displayed as a solid disk. How do I get it to just display as a circular outline with a transparent centre?

I've had a look in the help and it makes no sense to me, probably because I'm not used to the drawing terms like stroke and dither. What's wrong with background and border, eh?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

so that it doesn't do the filling. But then again, I've never used the Android API - this is really just a guess based on the docs :)

Comment: Nice one! Is Stroke a graphics term then? as I've never heard of it.
Thanks tho,

- Frink

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't guess. He answers....And when he answers.. he... I'll shut up now.

Comment: As an Android lover a big fan of Jon Skeet, I am glad to have encountered his Android related answer (I only saw him in C# related posts). You are a big inspiration to me. Thank you.

Comment: Java - C# , Android ... you are everywhere why ?