# how to fill my custom view in black color but that in center will transparent circle?

Tags: android, canvas

How to fill my custom view in black color but that in center will transparent circle? Without using bitmaps.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't understand what you trying to achieve. Do you have any reference image.

Comment: I try draw black view with hole in center.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public class MyView extends View {
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**FINAL UPDATE**

This is with black background:
`paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't help me. Circle will be transparent. I want to draw circle but fill area outside circle.

Comment: what do you mean by transparent? you want only borders to be visible or what?

Comment: I want to draw circle but fill area outside circle.

Comment: so you do `rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` and then draw circle, what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, this method does not work. If I wrong please will show the code how you draw circle?

Comment: @Sabrak, let me do that. I'll respond you when I'm done

Comment: @Sabrak, I've just edited answer, I've checked, everything works fine. just change `paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);` and that's it. Another option: you may get your root view, get color from it and pass to that class as parameter. I hope it is done. Please, if you satisfied with this answer, accept it and question will be closed. Happy coding :)

Comment: In your code circle has a color (#CD5C5C) but I want that circle will be transparent. Black view with hole.

Comment: I'm sorry, have you tried to google or use search? Once more sorry, but I have to downvote this question 1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004387/android-drawcircle-with-different-colour-border 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487216/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-transparent-middle 3.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEcQFjAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Ftopic%2Fandroid-developers%2Fp7je7xbwhfE&ei=JOU4Vd8fhY-4BIv6gJAE&usg=AFQjCNEVZXhTYhHO0DBvhYxIO4_orSicwQ&sig2=0eQDYhuZmqz1CEwCydpdng&bvm=bv.91427555,d.c2E

Answer (score 0):

Its drawable, which set as background for you view. But circle is not transparent.. Maybe you can set the color you want for circle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>

        <shape
            android:innerRadius="50dp"
            android:shape="ring">
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create transparent effect paint with xfermod and transparent color

```
clearPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)
clearPaint.color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.transparent, null)
```

Also you need to disable hardware accelarator from view

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

I give you an example of a custom view:

```
class MyCustomView(context: Context) : View(context) {
    private val paint: Paint by lazy { Paint() }
    private lateinit var clearPaint: Paint
    
    init {      
        clearPaint = Paint()
        clearPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)
    }

    public override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        //draw blackbackground
        paint.color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.black, null)
        canvas.drawPaint(paint)

        val circleRadius: Float = parent.height.toFloat() / 8  //example radius
        clearPaint.color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.transparent, null)
        //circle
        canvas.drawCircle(parent.width.toFloat() / 2, parent.height.toFloat() / 2, circleRadius, clearPaint)
    }    
}
```

(Kotlin solution)